# Char array **array changing to int C

Tags: c, arrays, char, integer

I have some words in **words and I'm trying to get transfer them to integer. Im not sure how to do it, there's my try but it shows me core dump. Any help how to do it?

```
unsigned long long int strToInt(char **words, int nr) {
    unsigned long long int int_value;
    sscanf(words[nr],"%llu",&int_value);

    return int_value;
}
```

Comment: You want to do what?

Comment: try `strtoull` to convert a string to an `unsigned long long`

Comment: Are you sure that `words[nr]` is `NULL` terminated? Also, check the return code of `sscanf` to make sure about the conversion.

Comment: By the way, even though every beginner gets exposed to `char**` (a “ragged array”) in the first few weeks of learning C/C++, it’s very rarely the data structure you really want. You more often want a rectangular array for dense arrays or something like compressed sparse row for sparse ones.